# How to hide an external url from my user in a Django project?

Tags: python, django

I have a model in my django project that uses the `UrlField` to keep external urls files. I use the `@login_required` in my view to prevent anonymous users to get access to this content. But, in this case, a logged-in user can retrieve this information and post anywhere for everyone to use.

My intention was to create a specific path on my `urls.py`, with the model id as one of the parameters, and in the view called by this url it would fetch the content in the `UrlField` and serve the user without display any external link. Something like a proxy or mask for external urls.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I've tried to use `HttpResponseRedirect`, but in the end the browser keep showing the url I want to hide.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make your statics files server talk with django, maybe with this

https://github.com/johnsensible/django-sendfile